# Because of in the beginning of a sentence

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions

Is this sentence right?

" I eventually go to that restaurant. Because of the prices I can't afford to go there very often"

Can I start a sentence using "Because of"??

Thanks

Comment: What in particular do you think is wrong?

Comment: The second sentence sounds weird to me. Is it completely right? For me it is missing a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly you can. I would not use a comma myself - because when I read it out, I would not normally pause there, and a comma **always** represents the end of a breath group - but it would be equally fine with a comma, and I would read it accordingly.